# Lot of warnings when applying pedantic GCC keys to project in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, mingw, compiler-warnings

**Intro**

Some time ago I find, that pedantic GCC keys are usefull, and can advice me to write cleaner code.
When I code simple console C++ app and compile it with parameters:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Weffc++ -Wold-style-cast
-Wconversion -Winit-self -Wunreachable-code
```

*(here is fully documented information about all of them: [Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), [Options Controlling C++ Dialect](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html))*

---

**Problem**

Now, I'm using Qt 4.8.4 with MinGW compiler to build apps.
The problem is that when I add to my `.pro`-file next lines:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Weffc++ -Wold-style-cast
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wconversion -Winit-self
```

I got a **lot** of warnings what does from Qt's sources, but not from my sources.

---

**Example**

Simple Qt GUI project with parameters wrote above in `.pro`-file gives 517 warnings like:

> D:\Qt\4.8.4\src\corelib\global\qglobal.h:981: warning: base class 'struct QIntegerForSize<4>' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]
>
> D:\Qt\4.8.4\src\corelib\tools\qpoint.h:174: warning: conversion to 'float' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
>
> ...

And so on.

---

**Question**

How to avoid applying pedantic parameters to Qt's sources, and use that parameters only at my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mark them as system headers using GCC's [`-isystem`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) flag, you won't see warnings.  (See also http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html).

Comment: Yep! You are totally right!
In my case (on Windows) I got it to work as I wish by adding 

    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem "D:\\Qt\\4.8.4\\include"
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wold-style-cast
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wconversion -Winit-self

To my `.pro`-file.

Thanx a lot!